# What DNS records should I set up for a new server?

Tags: domain-name-system

It is an ordinary server: we will run a web site on and it should be able to send/recieve email.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set up an A record, a PTR and an MX record, which points to the A record.

A: Mapping hostname to IP (server.foo.net -> 11.22.33.44)
PTR: Reverse mapping of the above (11.22.33.44 -> server.foo.net)
MX: Tells foreign mail server who takes mail for your **domain** (foo.net) (MX = server.foo.net)

HTH

Comment: Note that the PTR record will be in the reverse DNS zone, which is handled by whoever owns/provides your IP addresses.  Usually this will be your ISP or co-location provider.  In some cases, with AT&T especially, they will want to delegate the reverse DNS to your DNS servers, so be ready for that if needed.

Answer (score 4):

To state the most obvious only, you will need an [A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_record) record for the domain you wish to use pointing to that server, and you'll need to specify that server in the [MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mx_record) records of your domain. You will probably also want to setup [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [SRV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) records as well, to help legitimize the standing of the email server.

Is there anything more specific you'd like some help with?

Ehtyar.

Comment: Yes. I would like to hear more about interaction with mail servers. What records should I set up so they won't treat my e-mail messages as spam?

Comment: As PEra mentioned, you should also have a PTR record in place which I forgot to mention. That and SPF should have you up and running no trouble.